How to center v-app-bar and v-system-bar in web built with vuetify
Environment: Nuxt + Vue 3.x + Vuetify 3.x
Below is my web page and pages/index.vue
<script setup lang="ts">

</script>

<template>
    <v-app style="width: 800px;margin: auto;" class="border-red " >

    <v-system-bar style="width: 800px;margin: auto;">System bar</v-system-bar>
    <v-app-bar  class="border-blue " style="width: 800px;margin: auto;">
      App Bar <v-app-bar-title>APP TITLE</v-app-bar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <v-container >
        <h1>HELLO MAIN</h1>
      </v-container>

    </v-main>
    <v-footer>
      FOOTER
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>

</template>

<style scoped>
.border-red {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.border-blue {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
</style>


I want to know how to center the system bar and app bar just like v-main and v-footer.

Try wrapping your content with v-layout to see if it helps

@fOURP Thanks I put  outside . And it works.

@fOURP why did you deleted your answer?

@kissu Tbh i wasn't really sure of my answer. Cause with v-layout, v-footer showed vertical and then you had to move v-footer outside of layout or change something else. Dunno..

@fOURP keep it, if it solved OP's issue. You can always refine it or propose a CSS solution but that's OP's decision to make. :)

I think you are looking for v-layout. Just wrap your content with it.
  <v-layout>
    <v-system-bar>System bar</v-system-bar>
    <v-app-bar
      class="border-blue"
      style="width: 800px; margin: auto"
    >
      App Bar <v-app-bar-title>APP TITLE</v-app-bar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <h1>HELLO MAIN</h1>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
    <v-footer app style="border: 5px solid green"> FOOTER </v-footer>
  </v-layout>

Playground
Docs

With your code, although the width of system bar and app bar now can be adjusted to 800px and located in red box,  is now moved to the right of , instead of below .

You are right. I edited my answer and added the "app" prop on footer which gives the footer a fixed position at the bottom of the viewport.
